# Can a diamond pipe prevent water from freezing and bursting the pipe?

Tags: pressure, water, material-science, stress-strain, states-of-matter

I know [a diamond vacuum blimp](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/could-a-vacuum-airship-be-possible) is not possible because it will implode under air pressure.

Is it possible for a diamond pipe to keep from bursting with frozen water?

I found [nothing online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=diamond+pipe+water+burst&ia=web) except Black Diamond, WA, Blue Diamond Plumbing, Diamond Glass Co, etc.

Comment: Try [this web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pipes+that+don%27t+burst+frozen&t=lm&ia=web) for more practical advice.  If you can afford diamond water pipes, you can probably afford to move home to a warmer place !

Comment: Use a rubber pipe, and it will expand as needed.

Comment: @DavidWhite What effect does very cold weather have on rubber ?

Comment: @DavidWhite I believe the standard is [PEX](http://www.pexinfo.com/) but I was mostly interested if diamond can withstand the expansive force of a phase change of water.

Comment: @Chloe, there is more stress on elbows than straight pipe.  Of course, I can't imagine how you would fabricate either in diamond, and the cost would be prohibitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diamond isn't the strongest material (and certainly not the cheapest for a given strength).  It is possible to construct vessels that are stronger than the pressure created by the freezing ice (at least small ones).  It needs to withstand 300MPa.  Looking online, you can find pipe manufacturers that make pipes with maximum pressures in that region.

It's possible you would have failures at other locations (like faucets that are not so strongly constructed) as the water in the pipe is pressurized.  And you would probably be paying more for the pipes than it would cost to repair several failures in regular pipes.

Answer (score 2):

The other problem with diamond as a structural material is that if struck by a sudden blow, it shatters into pieces. Brittle behavior like this is not a good thing in piping systems.